# What does "?:" do in regex?

Tags: regex

I wanted to match anything but a string using regex. I did some Googling and found this: `^(?:(?!test).)*`
What do ?: and ?! do? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(?:) is *non-capturing*.  That means that a match occurs as usual, but the parentheses are only for grouping (in this case to attach a `*` operator to the entire thing); the matched value cannot be pulled out later with $1 or \1.

(?!) is a negative lookahead assertion.  That means that it matches if the string in the parentheses *does not* exist there.

See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html for some more operators.  While regex varies in different languages, they're fairly similar.

Answer (score 0):

yes ... and (?!) is a "zero-width negative look-ahead assertion." according to "perldoc perlre".

It means don't match the thing in the parens.  Tje example from the docs is:

```
For example "/foo(?!bar)/" matches any occurrence of "foo" that isn’t followed by "bar".
```

So in this example foobar wouldn't match, but fooxbar would, as would foo and foofoo and so on.

Oh yes, so the example you gave should match anything not containing "test".  I think it's clearer to match /test/ and negate outside the regex evaluation, as in "grep -v test"

Answer (score 0):

The ?! indicates a negative look ahead.  The expression containing the negative look ahead will only return a match if the expression inside the negative look ahead fails to match.  This means that "(?!test)." will only return a match if "test" is not matched.

The outer grouping "(?:(?!test).)" is called a passive grouping and is functionally equivalent to "((?!test).)".  The difference is that with a passive grouping, no back references are created, so it's more efficient.